# Looking for advice on how to add routes

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, screen

I'm very new in all this, so please don't judge me for asking something that many of you know so well.
Basically I'm looking for some advice, how I can add route to second screen in my first app. I can share the code, if you need. I have icons row, and I'm wondering how I can add route to one of the icons?

Comment: [The flutter website has several guides relating to navigation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation). I suggest you look at [Navigate to a new screen and back](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) and [Navigate with named routes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap one of your icons in a `GestureDetector` widget. And call `Navigator.push()` on its `onTap` method to navigate to the second screen. Follow the below example

```
GestureDetector(
 child: Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
 onTap: () {
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()));
 },
),
```

Take a look at the `Navigator` class to find out more about other navigation options.

The `GestureDetector` widget allows you to detect gestures such as a tap on the screen.

Call the below method to return back to the first screen

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Once you are familiar with this process, take a look at named routes as mentioned in @[mmcdon20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647501/looking-for-advice-on-how-to-add-routes#comment128327512_72647501)'s comment